# AOL Mail no longer works: Error 1 - COFE error 1714?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, email

I've upgraded to the new tor bundle several weeks ago and I love it so far.  However, since the upgrade, I am no longer able to access my email (AOL webmail). The error I get when I sign in is "Error 1 - COFE error 1714".  They suggest I clear cookies, cache and restart in "safe" mode.  Below is their suggestion:

> Browser security settings sometimes disrupt sign-in. In Internet Explorer, try selecting “Enable Protected Mode” in both the Internet zone and Trusted sites zone. On Firefox, try using Safe Mode.
>   You also might try deleting your browser history. Find this in the “Tools” menu — and make sure to clear (delete) cookies!

Of course I'm OS X 10.7.5 so their solution really doesn't help. Unfortunately, I'm not the most savvy with some of this stuff, but I have some questions:

1. Is there a work around?
2. Is there a tor-friendly webmail?

Comment: I've removed your third question as it is offtopic here. This site is specifically for questions about Tor; mail forwarding setup doesn't fall into that cateogry I'm afraid. Thanks for using Tor.SE!